# SQL Server significant digits

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, significant-digits

I have a variable that I want to return a max of 5 to the left of the decimal and always 3 to the right

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(14),CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3),
        DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@ProcessTime,GETDATE()))/@OneThousand)
```

Now variables are defined as

```
DECLARE @ProcessTime DATETIME 
DECLARE @OneThousand DECIMAL(8,3)
SET @OneThousand = 1000.000
```

This always returns something like

```
0.003000000000
```

I guess I can solve my problem with a left function, but my question is why does this happen at all.  If the Minimum variable of decimal defined, `@OneThousand`, is 3 shouldn't the return value have 3 decimals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the division of `DECIMAL(8,3)` by `DECIMAL(8,3)`gives a datatype of `DECIMAL(20,12)` to see this

```
DECLARE @ProcessTime DATETIME =getdate()
DECLARE @OneThousand DECIMAL(8,3)
SET @OneThousand = 1000.000

DECLARE @v SQL_VARIANT

SET @v = CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,3),
        DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,@ProcessTime,GETDATE()))/@OneThousand

SELECT
    CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'BaseType') AS VARCHAR(30)) AS BaseType,
    CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'Precision') AS INT) AS Precision,
    CAST(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@v, 'Scale') AS INT) AS Scale
```

The BOL section that explains why `decimal(20,12)` [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)

```
Operation:        e1 / e2
Result precision: p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
Result scale:     max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
```

So in your case

```
Result precision: 8 - 3 + 3 + max(6, 3 + 8 + 1) = 20
Result scale:     max(6, 3 + 8 + 1)             = 12
```

Comment: Err--- I just changed my parenthesis so it now does int/Decimal(8,3) and then convert but again that does not explain what I always thought that int/anything is int?? or why Decimal(20,12) for the above.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

```
SELECT CAST(DATEDIFF(ms, @processDate, GETDATE()) / 1000.000 AS decimal(8,3))
```